# get vs Readonly vs constant in c#

Tags: c#

What is the difference between {get;} and Readonly in the following C# code?

```
String name { get { return "Tom"; } }
const String name = "Tom";
readonly String name = "Tom";
```

please explain with simple problem or any reference.

Comment: You have already read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719699/when-should-use-readonly-and-get-only-properties)?

Comment: @KevinWallis: Different people have different conventions for that. It makes no difference whatsoever (assuming there's no conflict).

Comment: Do you understand that the first of these is a property and the other two are fields?

Comment: @JonSkeet I read many books about coding (maybe not as much as you :D) and many of them said that in C# `string` should be used for declaration and `String` for calling `String` functions only for readability reasons. But as you said: "Different people have different conventions for that"

Comment: You can't change readonly fields (or constants) after initializartion(so only inline or via constructor). You can change properties without setters from within this class if there is a backing field, otherwise the behaviour is similar to a readonly field. But they are different anyway, one is a field and the other a property.

Comment: @KevinWallis: Well I use `string` universally, and Jeffrey Richter (CLR via C#) uses `String` universally. Personally I'd prefer a convention which was consistent over one which uses different names for the same type in different places. (How does that make anything more readable?) But I certainly don't think there's any good reason to ask others on SO to use one form or the other - it's not like the well-established conventions around property names (so `name` should be `Name` in the first line in this question).

Comment: @JonSkeet okay good point, I deleted my comment

Comment: @JonSkeet when we talk about the first line, does it compile? Because `;` is missing

Comment: @KevinWallis: True. Will fix that myself, as it's clearly a typo.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for reminder, I have read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c) to know the difference between a field and a property.