# How to use C# readonly property? Using get set or lambda?

Tags: c#

```
namespace BrowserCompatabilityTests
{
    public static class Selectors
    {
        public static string activateDeviceButton = "#root > div > div > div > 
        div.row.activate--full-page > div:nth-child(2) > form > 
        div.form__actions.flex > button";
    }
}
```

I was asked to update this activateDevice field to a readonly getter property. Is there a C# convention to use {get,set} or lambda?

Comment: Just change the `=` to a `=>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719699/when-should-use-readonly-and-get-only-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may declare ReadOnly properties either with a get (without set):

```
public string activateDeviceButton { get{ return someValue;} }
```

Or with a Lambda Expression:

```
   public string activateDeviceButton => someValue;
```

Comment: @cja and get only means?

Comment: A property with a get but not a set. readonly is a modifier applied to fields, not properties.

Answer (score 3):

Try this variant, this sets the property value exactly once.

```
public static string activateDeviceButton { get; } = "#root > div > div > div > div.row.activate--full-page > div:nth-child(2) > form > div.form__actions.flex > button";
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into getter and setter properties.  Here is how it would potentially look:

```
public static string activateDeviceButton { get {return value;}}
```